# Outlook conditional formatting - weird behavior ? ( rules are not always applies)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010

I have outlook 2010 at my work where my email there is : `Roi@work.com`. *( you could see the real email in the pic , since I don't want crawlers to scan it , I changed it here in the question).*

I also have Gmail account which is `Roi@MyGmail.com`.

The outlook is under a domain `work.com`

**MyGoal**

- Roi's Gmail emails sent to my Roi's work -> to be in *green*
- Roi's work emails sent to Roi's work ( i can send to myself) -> to be in *red*.

Currently the settings are the default settings :

[image]

Ok - so I created a rule for gmail :

[image]

And as you can see it does work :

[image]

So now let's add the work to work rule :

[image]

Ok so let's test it by sending work mail to myself :

[image]

**BANG** — doesn't work.

[image]

**Question**

Why don't I see the RED color in the work mail ?

PS I noticed something strange :

If I set the "FROM" field (*via pressing "From..." and select myself from a list*) -  with my outlook NAME which is "Royi Namir" ( as opposed to specify my direct email) as in here :

[image]

Then it does work :

[image]

**Question :**

Am I missing something here ? because it should work in both cases - 
How can I make it work with simple email addresses ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work for you with your company internal email addresses. Within the company, Outlook will resolve known emails to email alias or actual names. In your case it resolves to your name (won't be mentioning it in the post). You can simply check it by exporting the entire message to text format and opening it with your text editor. When you look at **"From:"** field you will realize that your email address is simply not there. Only the actual names can be found in **"From:"** field.

Conditional formatting does simple matching of given strings against contents of given fields. So matching your company email against contents of **"From:"** field will never return any positive results. Note that string comparison is not case sensitive, no wildcards allowed, however partial names are allowed.

The situation with any external email, or any email unknown within the company network is different. Outlook will not be able to resolve the email to any known name or email alias. So it will have an entry in **"From:"** field in format **Name (email@domain.com)**. And in this case specifying the actual email in your conditional formatting rule will work correctly.

Also, note that it is not possible to change this behavior as internal email addresses are resolved to names by Exchange and there is no setting to stop that from happening.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly , for in-organization email I _should_ use the actual name ( case sensitive BTW ? )  & for outsiders users , I _should_ use the normal  plain emails addresses ?

Comment: That is almost correct. The only thing that I would want to emphasize is that for in-organization email you should use whatever the email resolves to. It can be name, email alias or something else. It is Name followed by Last Name in your case. And it is not case sensitive. Also, I want to note that the most rational way of doing it is by clicking on **From..** button and selecting actual user from the list. This way you will never make any typos.

Comment: I have updated my answer to add details about string matching being not case sensitive

Comment: thanks i'll try it. I will ask if I have a problem :-) tnx